# Android - Java - WebView >> Count Page Loading time, if not loaded, intent new activity

Tags: java, android, webview

```
WebView web;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  
    String uid = extras.getString("uid"); 
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/android/login.php?uid="+uid);
                                                }

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient  {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                                                                        }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)   {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
                                                                        }
                                                }
```

This is the code of my webview activity.
I'd like to implement a page loading function which is It will count in background when URL called.If URL doesnt load completely in 5000ms, the code below must run automatically.
I cant figure out how to figure It.

```
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InternetError.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

I've tried lot of methods but never get correct result.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, please change you implementation of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` so that it does not call `loadUrl` on the WebView, it's wrong to do that. The URL load is in progress when you get that callback, you must not start it again.

Second, to solve your issue can you post a delayed message to a Handler that will execute your error code after the desired timeout, and remove that message if WebViewClient.onPageFinished comes first?